# How to use "this" and not "this" selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors, this

I have 4 divs with content like below:

```
<div class="prodNav-Info-Panel">content</div>
<div class="prodNav-Usage-Panel">content</div>
<div class="prodNav-Guarantee-Panel">content</div>
<div class="prodNav-FAQ-Panel">content</div>
```

And a navigation list like this:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a class="prodNav-Info" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="prodNav-Usage" ></a></li>
    <li><a class="prodNav-Guarantee"></a></li>
    <li><a class="prodNav-FAQ" ></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the page is first displayed I show all the content by executing this:

```
$('div.prodNav-Usage-Panel').fadeIn('slow');
$('div.prodNav-Guarantee-Panel').fadeIn('slow');
$('div.prodNav-FAQ-Panel').fadeIn('slow');
$('div.prodNav-Info-Panel').fadeIn('slow');
```

Now, when you click the navigation list item it reveals the clicked content and hides the others, like this:

```
    $('.prodNav-Info').click( function() {
        $('div.prodNav-Info-Panel').fadeIn('slow');
        $('div.prodNav-Usage-Panel').fadeOut('slow');
        $('div.prodNav-Guarantee-Panel').fadeOut('slow');
        $('div.prodNav-FAQ-Panel').fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

So what I have is 4 separate functions because I do not know which content is currently displayed.  I know this is inefficient and can be done with a couple of lines of code.  It seems like there is a way of saying: when this is clicked, hide the rest.

Can I do this with something like $(this) and $(not this)?

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case you maybe able to use the [`.sibilings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method something like this:

```
$(this).fadeIn().sibilings().fadeOut()
```

Otherwise, lets say that you have a set of elements stored somewhere that points to all of your elements:

```
// contains 5 elements:
var $hiders = $(".prodNavPanel");

// somewhere later:
$hiders.not("#someElement").fadeOut();
$("#someElement").fadeIn();
```

Also, I would suggest changing the classes for your `<div>` and `<a>` to something more like:

```
<div class="prodNavPanel" id="panel-Info">content</div>
....
<a class="prodNavLink" href="#panel-Info">info</a>
```

This gives you a few advantages over your HTML.  First: the links will have useful hrefs.  Second: You can easily select all your `<div>`/`<a>` tags.  Then you can do this with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var $panels = $(".prodNavPanel");
  $(".prodNavLink").click(function() {
     var m = this.href.match(/(#panel.*)$/);
     if (m) {
       var panelId = m[1];
       $panels.not(panelId).fadeOut();
       $(panelId).fadeIn();
       return false; // prevents browser from "moving" the page
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have to study this but it looks really good...thanks for the quick response.